# AWS EC2 hosted website map to domain name from godaddy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I purchased domain name from GoDaddy. www.***ta.com
I am using AWS to host virtual machine (EC2 instance).
Now my web site is up and running on EC2 instance. I can access my webpage from public IP address.

I want to use domain that i purchased from GoDaddy www.***ta.com.

I follow online help

Create hosted zone add record set 
 Type A - with public IP4 in AWS Route 53 and public ip address of EC2 machine.
When i tested it works on AWS but not from the browser.

Anything missing? can you please provide some inputs?

Comment: What do you mean that it "works on AWS"? From some other instance only?

Comment: let me clarify this. With AWS console "Test Record Set"

Comment: Usually it takes some time to work. the dns has to propagate. I assume you correctly imported domain from GoDaddy to R53.

Comment: do i need to import domain name to R53?

Comment: Have to check how to set it up. These could be good start: [Here](https://medium.com/@jryancanty/domain-by-godaddy-dns-by-route53-fc7acf2f55800) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/MigratingDNS.html) .

Comment: If you purchased your domain in GoDaddy your DNS Register is GoDaddy, so you need to create a dns record type A (because you are using elastic IP in the instance not a load balancer) for your domain pointing to the elastic IP of your instance. In AWS is working because may be is a private Hosted Zone and the EC2 can resolve it, but if you don't migrate from GoDaddy your DNS register or changed in GoDaddy the NS (Name Server) of your domain to the NS servers in AWS, the website will not visible in internet under your domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either set the DNS records in godaddy DNS zone or Map the DNS servers to Route53 and then create the Zone file.

For setting DNS in Godaddy -

- Go to Manage DNS and select your domain.
- Add a A record - Enter the IP of your EC2 instance as value and @ as key.
- Add another CNAME Record - www as key value as @
- After sometime your domain will start working.

For setting DNS in Route53 -

- Go to Route53 and create a domain by entering your domain name.
- In godaddy changethe DNS server 1, server 2, server 3, server 4 to the  Name Servers received from Route 53.
- after 24 hours your Domain name servers will start pointing to Route53.
- Now come back to Route53 and add A record with your ec2 instance IP address.